# Explicit behavior of a sequence of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

Let $N \geqslant 0$ an integer and $(u_n)_{n \geqslant 0}$ be the sequence defined as follow: 
$$u_n := \int _0^{+ \infty} e^{-nt} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} \frac{t^k}{k!}\right)^n\,\mathrm{d} t.$$

> Find an explicit constant $C_N$ only depending on $N$ (explicit but not necessarily computable, e.g $\displaystyle \int _{\mathbb{R}} e^{-u^2} \, \mathrm{d}u$ is such a constant) such that : $$u_n \leqslant \frac{C_N}{n^{1/N}}$$ for all

For $N=1$ one gets $C_1=1$. The real problem starts with $N=2$: I use the change of variable $u=\sqrt{n}t$ which allow us to write :

$$v_n:= \sqrt{n}\int_1 ^{+\infty} e^{-nt} \left( 1+t\right)^n\,\mathrm{d} t  = \int_0 ^{1} e^{-\sqrt{n}u +n \log \left(1+\frac{u}{\sqrt{n}}\right)}\,\mathrm{d} t  = \int_0 ^{1} e^{-u^2/2 + \sum_{k=3}^{+\infty}  (-1)^k \frac{u^k}{kn^{k/2-1}}}\,\mathrm{d} t  .$$

Then, Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem enable us to write that $v_n \to \int_0^{+ \infty} e^{-u^2} \, \mathrm{d}u$. For the remaining part of the integral defining $u_n$ one can perform other methods (using the concavity of the logarithm). This shows that the asymptotic comportement is the one expected but does not gives an explicit global bound for $\sqrt{n} u_n$ !

If anyone knows how to find such bounds, please feel free to answer, even if you think that your method is not optimal.

Thanks,

Comment: You may notice that the Taylor series of $e^{-t}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{t^k}{k!}$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin is given by $$1-\frac{t^N}{N!}+\ldots $$ hence the integral is expected to behave like $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{n t^N}{N!}\right)\,dt =\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\Gamma(N+1)}{n}\right)^{1/N}$$

Comment: For short, Laplace's method is the key: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you for looking at the problem. Still, I know how to get the asymptotic behavior (with something near the Laplace method you refer to) but I want an explicit bound for $\sqrt{n}u_n$ not an asymptotic bound

Comment: But are you interested in  the general case or just in the $N=2$ case?

Comment: In the $N=2$ case you may use the inequality $$(1+t)e^{-t} \leq \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{t+3}\right)$$

Comment: Or the inequality $$(1+t)e^{-t}\leq \exp\left(-\frac{t^2}{2+\frac{3}{2}t}\right) $$

Comment: I am interested in the general case. In the original message I just explained what I tried. Thanks for the $N=2$ case, I'll try with your inequality

Comment: Do you need the smallest $C_N$ or just an explicit one that works?

Comment: Just an explicit that works, easily computable with a cumputer (in an approximate way of course). It would be sufficient. In fact I am very open on the answers !